# How to fix 'TypeError: this.form.get is not a function' in karma test runner

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular7, formbuilder, angular-test, form-control

I am using `formbuilder.group` to create reactive form with the formcontrol `name` in `ngOnInit()` and made a get function for name, when I run `ng test` I get error as below

- I have created the test case for my component using Simon Test extension
- I tried importing `ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule` in spec.ts
- I tried changing `form.get('name')` to `form.controls.name`

#### Error in karma-test runner

```
Test1Component ngOnInit makes expected calls
TypeError: this.form.get is not a function
TypeError: this.form.get is not a function
    at Test1Component.get [as name] (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/test1/test1.component.ts:27:22)
    at Test1Component../src/app/test1/test1.component.ts.Test1Component.printVal (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/test1/test1.component.ts:23:22)
    at Test1Component.SpyStrategy.exec (http://localhost:9877/absoluteC:/Users/ratnsing/Desktop/Ratnesh/Angular7/Xv1/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:5083:19)
    at Test1Component.spy (http://localhost:9877/absoluteC:/Users/ratnsing/Desktop/Ratnesh/Angular7/Xv1/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:4873:44)
    at Test1Component.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9877/absoluteC:/Users/ratnsing/Desktop/Ratnesh/Angular7/Xv1/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:4849:20)
    at Test1Component.printVal (http://localhost:9877/absoluteC:/Users/ratnsing/Desktop/Ratnesh/Angular7/Xv1/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:4890:50)
    at Test1Component../src/app/test1/test1.component.ts.Test1Component.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/test1/test1.component.ts:19:10)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/test1/test1.component.spec.ts:28:17)
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:289:1)
```

#### test1.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test1',
  templateUrl: './test1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test1.component.css']
})
export class Test1Component implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['Init Value']
    });
    this.printval();
  }

  printVal() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }

  get name() {
    return this.form.get('name');
  }
}
```

#### test1.component.spec.ts

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Test1Component } from './test1.component';
describe('Test1Component', () => {
  let component: Test1Component;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<Test1Component>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const formBuilderStub = { group: object1 => ({}) };
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [Test1Component],
      providers: [{ provide: FormBuilder, useValue: formBuilderStub }]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Test1Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
  it('can load instance', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  describe('ngOnInit', () => {
    it('makes expected calls', () => {
      const formBuilderStub: FormBuilder = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(
        FormBuilder
      );
      spyOn(component, 'printVal').and.callThrough();
      spyOn(formBuilderStub, 'group').and.callThrough();
      component.ngOnInit();
      expect(component.printVal).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(formBuilderStub.group).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

I found that `.get` is a part of AbstractControl property,
expecting al the test cases to pass...

Comment: any update on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Can u try:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

beforeEach(async(() => {
    const formBuilderStub = { group: object1 => ({}) };
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [CommonModule,ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [Test1Component],
      providers: [FormBuilder]
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Test1Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
}));
```

1. Remove overriding of `FormBuilder` service

   `providers: [{ provide: FormBuilder, useValue: formBuilderStub }]`
2. Import `ReactiveFormsModule` in `TestBed`
3. Add `.compileComponents();`
4. Put it in `async` block

Comment: Thanks for help, but without async also it seems to work fine, I am getting another error  `Cannot find 'get' of undefined`, its basically coming from the getter function that is created to access the formcontrol in ts file exactly like in the following example of angular website

[stackblitz_example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dkavomgddkq)